# Querying a null boolean field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When querying a boolean field that is null why does

```
Select * From MyTableName where [boolfieldX] <> 1
```

not return any rows with null in [boolfieldX]?  1 <> null I would have expected rows with null to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to test for `NULL` values with comparison operators, such as `=`, `<`, or `<>`.

You have to use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators instead, or you have to use functions like `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE()`

```
Select * From MyTableName where [boolfieldX] <> 1 OR [boolfieldX] IS NULL
```

**OR**

```
Select * From MyTableName where ISNULL([boolfieldX],0) <> 1
```

Read more about null comparison in [Stackoverflow Documentation](http://www.riptutorial.com/sql-server/example/17804/null-comparison)

Read more about `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE()` Functions in [Stackoverflow Documentation](http://www.riptutorial.com/sql-server/example/25800/coalesce---)

Comment: [@Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641914/graham) please try to encourage fixing links to documentation instead of just outright removing the links and surrounding paragraphs, leave comments.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's because null is an unknown value. You can't query against an unknown 'value'. In my opinion, referring to null as a 'value' is an oxymoron because it represents an unknown. Using the operators "Is Null" and "Not Is Null" in conjunction with whatever selection criteria will return the desired results, or translating it by converting a null an alternate value will work like this: IsNull([boolfield], 'some compatible value')

Answer (score -2):

Hi try to use this query:

```
select * from mytablename where [boolFieldX] is null And [boolFieldX] <> 1
```